# Python on JSON: How to deal with messy inceptive files

Tags: python, json, api

Recently I'm working a lot on JSON files from API pulls and when I drill down it gets messy really fast, inceptions of dictionaries and I find my code hard to read or understand, I care to improve my readability and approach to that matter.

Example:
Json file -> keys -> dictionaries -> certain key needed -> another dict.

```
for id in data['units']:
    for header in data['units'][id]:
        toon_id = data['units'][id]['ID']
        if header == 'Abilities':
            for ability in data['units'][id][header]:
                for header in ability:
                    if header == 'NameKey': 
                        to_sql.append(ability[header])
                    if header == 'Levels':
                        for level in ability[header]:
                            for key in level:
                                rel = ['UpgradeDescription','Requirements']
                                if key == 'UpgradeDescription': to_sql.append(level[key])
                                if key == 'Requirements':
                                    for i in level[key]:
                                        if i == 'GearTier': to_sql.append(level[key][i])
                                if len(to_sql) == 3:
                                    to_sql_total.append(to_sql)
                                    to_sql = []
                                elif len(to_sql) == 1 and ability['NameKey'] not in to_sql: to_sql.insert(0,ability['NameKey'])
```

Please share your knowledge and best approaches to this kind of data. my end goal is to traslate JSON file yo relational db.

Thanks in advance.

Data sample:

```
"units": {
        "7266520144288097": {
            "ID": 7266520144288097,
            "NameKey": "SHERIFF_OF_NOTTINGHAM_UNIT_NAME",
            "UnitStats": {
                "Offense": 50,
                "Defense": 12,
                "Health": 216,
                "Recovery": 0,
                "CritChance": 0.05,
                "CritPower": 1.5,
                "AttackSpeed": 0.2,
                "Speed": 100,
                "Potency": 0.0,
                "Tenacity": 0.05,
                "Accuracy": 0.0,
                "Evasion": 0.0
            },
            "StatProgressionTable": 6619604581022230,
            "GearSlotTable": 3,
            "GearTiers": [
                {
                    "GearTierSlot": [
                        {
                            "Offense": true,
                            "Defense": false,
                            "Health": false,
                            "Recovery": false,
                            "CritChance": false,
                            "CritPower": false,
                            "AttackSpeed": false,
                            "ItemID": 5800404643593210,
                            "UnitLevel": 5,
                            "Speed": false,
                            "Potency": false,
                            "Tenacity": false,
                            "Accuracy": false,
                            "Evasion": false
                        },
                        {
                            "Offense": false,
                            "Defense": true,
                            "Health": false,
                            "Recovery": false,
                            "CritChance": false,
                            "CritPower": false,
                            "AttackSpeed": false,
                            "ItemID": 6291390382388483,
                            "UnitLevel": 1,
                            "Speed": false,
                            "Potency": false,
                            "Tenacity": false,
                            "Accuracy": false,
                            "Evasion": false
                        },
                        {
                            "Offense": false,
                            "Defense": false,
                            "Health": true,
                            "Recovery": false,
                            "CritChance": false,
                            "CritPower": false,
                            "AttackSpeed": false,
                            "ItemID": 3179470540328821,
                            "UnitLevel": 8,
                            "Speed": false,
                            "Potency": false,
                            "Tenacity": false,
                            "Accuracy": false,
                            "Evasion": false
                        },
                        {
                            "Offense": true,
                            "Defense": false,
                            "Health": false,
                            "Recovery": false,
                            "CritChance": false,
                            "CritPower": false,
                            "AttackSpeed": false,
                            "ItemID": 5800404643593210,
                            "UnitLevel": 5,
                            "Speed": false,
                            "Potency": false,
                            "Tenacity": false,
                            "Accuracy": false,
                            "Evasion": false
                        },
                        {
                            "Offense": false,
                            "Defense": false,
                            "Health": true,
                            "Recovery": false,
                            "CritChance": false,
                            "CritPower": false,
                            "AttackSpeed": false,
                            "ItemID": 3179470540328821,
                            "UnitLevel": 8,
                            "Speed": false,
                            "Potency": false,
```

Comment: Can you update the question to include a sample JSON input?

Comment: Have you considered treating the JSON as a tree and use text-book recursion methods to "walk the tree"? Or maybe JSONPath ?

Comment: A library like [`jq`](https://pypi.org/project/jq/) might make it simpler to transform your incoming JSON into a form more easily parsed for defining `to_sql`.

Comment: Thank you all for the respond; I'll check the libraries you mentioned and I attach a sample from part of the data that I pull

Comment: @NirAbutbul Update the post with a **VALID** json example. Share the expected records based on that json

Comment: By "inceptive" do you mean "deeply nested"? Or just what?

Comment: @balderman can you please express the meaning of valid, I did as best as I understood :/.  Karl deeply nested indeed

Comment: @MortenJensen I want to thank you publicly for your reference to JSONPATH, That exactly What I needed.

Comment: @NirAbutbul I’m glad you found it useful :)